# How do I change AD password through Powershell while enforcing password complexity requirements?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

```powershell
Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $ntaccount1 -NewPassword $pass -Reset
Set-ADUser -Identity $ntaccount1 -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true
```

The above command prompts to change the password and marks it as `expired` , however, if I force change the password to something that doesn't meet the password criteria, it will let me do it anyway. Is there a way to have it tell me that it is not a valid password to use?

Example:

Some passwords can be `abc123`.
More sophisticated accounts need to be `Abcd12345!`

Comment: There is no way to force a password reset with `Set-ADAccountPassword` that ignores complexity requirements. Are you talking about forcing password complexity *outside* AD policy?

Comment: Well I reset a password with blue123 and it didnt give any error, and it turns out it needed to be a more complex requirement. I did have errors turned off, so unless that would have hidden it...

Comment: If you try to reset an account password to that in ADUC, does it give you an error? And what do you mean by "errors turned off"? A password complexity issue for that cmdlet is a terminating error, so `$ErrorActionPreference` would not suppress it.

Comment: I did have $ErrorActionPreference enabled, but yes, I did reset a password to blue123 and it did not work, I had to make it Abcd12345! , I got no error telling me I couldn't do it. If I went into ActiveDirectory and tried to reset it to blue123 I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

A standard password reset will not enforce complexity/policy. If you want to do the policy enforcement, you're going to have to write a bunch of additional code to make an LDAP call that tells the DC to enforce policy. This blog post has C# code that shows you how to do this. You should be able to translate it to PowerShell without too much work. http://blog.msresource.net/2011/05/30/resetting-an-ad-ds-password-and-honouring-password-history-and-age-using-the-ldap_server_policy_hints-control/